# Azure B2C - Terms of Service checkbox for Social Signup/Signin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I would like to display the Terms of Service checkbox after the user signs up through an IDP (Facebook, Google, etc.)  How can I achieve this?

I am however encountering "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." after sign up.

Below are snippets of my code so far:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">
          <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" DefaultValue="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />

            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />

          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-SignUp" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialSignup" /></TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion" DefaultValue="V1" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: This happens when the output claims are impossible to be generated. Either they do not have a userInputType, not output by a validation technical profile, and don’t have a defaultValue. Review how you expect those output claims to be satisfied.

Comment: I checked my policy and I verified that:
-  extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice has a userInputType of CheckboxMultiSelect
-  extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice has a default value of AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo

I am not sure about not output by a Validation Technical Profile part....  I use this as a validation profile: "AD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" and i have this in there
`
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" />
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new sample here which demonstrates the flow:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou-with-social

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've ran the policy as is and it works fine.  However, I can't seem to incorporate the changes into my policy.  As soon as I add 
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" /> in <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">, I get the error, "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."